# Is there a hook or function I can use to display all theme files being used on a current page?

Tags: functions, hooks

Basically I want to be able to see the names of files on the front-end - not just templates e.g. category/page templates, but the actual theme files like header.php/sidebar.php/footer.php and so on.

So I think the problem is what I've found so far doesn't have the depth I need and only goes as far as telling me what "template" is being used versus all the pieces that make up the "template".

I can't seem to find something that'll give me a PHP object for me `var_dump` and see what's available or a hook that I can manipulate. Does this actually exist or am I grasping for straws?

**What I looked into so far:**

- [How do you find out which template is serving the current page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page?lq=1)

  t31os' answer is helpful, but it only goes as deep as the container
  template, so if I call his function in header.php, it will tell me
  page.php instead of header.php. In other words, I want to know the
  exact file my function is calling out from.
- [Get Name of Current Template File](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file)

  This is a similar issue as the first question, and still using t310s'
  answer as reference.
- Also looked into the [wp_get_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) function, but that object only
  gives me info about the theme itself, rather than an array or list of
  files.

My goal is to write a function that would dynamically echo out all the file names or pieces on what's being viewed on the front-end . So a "Page" would echo page.php, sidebar.php, footer.php and header.php for example.

Please no plugins, I'd like to resolve this with PHP. I get that this might not be a simple answer, but I'd like a starting point at the very least - or at least know if it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has a function, [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php), that returns all the files that have been included during a request.

However, if you use that function you obtain **all** the files required: WordPress core files, plugin files...

You need a way to:

- Filter out files that do not belong to the theme and child theme (if any)
- Include only files loaded *after* the main template has been included

Also you need to call this function as late as possible; [`shutdown`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shutdown/) would be the better hook, however, [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/) should be fine, because it's rare that you include a file after that hook has been fired.

Regarding the 2 problems mentioned above, the first can be solved by filtering the array for files that only belong to the theme folder.

The second can be solved by using [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/), with a very low priority, to save the path of the main template, and then including in the output only files included after it.

Here's a class that implements what's said above. Put in a file and require from `functions.php`:

```
class IncludedPartGrabber
{    
    private $main;
    private $root;
    private $switch = false;

    public function setup( $template )
    {
        $this->root = wp_normalize_path( get_theme_root() ); // theme folder
        $this->main = wp_normalize_path( $template ); // main template

        return $template;
    }

    public function grab()
    {
        return array_filter( get_included_files(), array( $this, 'filter' ) );
    }

    private function filter( $file )
    {
        $norm =  wp_normalize_path( $file );
        if ( $norm === $this->main )
            $this->switch = TRUE; // after main template all files are good to be included

        return $this->switch && strpos( $norm, $this->root ) === 0; // true if file is in theme dir
    }
}
```

Use it like so, in your `functions.php`:

```
$grabber = new IncludedPartGrabber;

add_action( 'template_include', array( $grabber, 'setup' ) );

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() use($grabber) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $grabber->grab() ); // see your footer :)
    echo '</pre>';
} );
```

If you want to use inside a template file, in `functions.php` put:

```
global $grabber;
$grabber = new IncludedPartGrabber;

add_action( 'template_include', array( $grabber, 'setup' ) );
```

and then in the template file, e.g. `footer.php`:

```
<pre><?php print_r( $GLOBALS['grabber']->grab() ); ?></pre>
```

Of course you can use in `header.php` too, but from that file you'll get only the files loaded at the moment `header.php` has been included, e.g. `page.php` and `header.php`. PHP is a programming language, not a magic machine, and can't know which files are going to be included *before* they are actually included.

Comment: I like this solution because I don't have to use multiple functions to grab the header/footer/sidebar and then the general templates. It's all consolidated into one class and feels much cleaner. I've tried it out and I am getting all the templates printed in the footer. Of course I can re-work it so it's not printing out the array of paths - but this is a great start! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

`get_header`, `get_footer`, and `get_sidebar` all have corresponding actions that pass the name as an argument, so you can hook those actions, test for their existence via `locate_template` and log the names.

`get_template_part` has an action, but it's dynamic and includes the slug, so unless you know the slugs, those will be difficult to hook. what you can do is hook `all`, and string match the first part of the action, `get_template_part_`, which is exactly [what this What the File plugin does](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/):

```
add_action( 'all', 'save_template_parts', 1, 3 );

function save_template_parts( $tag, $slug = null, $name = null ) {
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $tag, 'get_template_part_' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if slug is set
    if ( $slug != null ) {

        // Templates array
        $templates = array();

        // Add possible template part to array
        if ( $name != null ) {
            $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
        }

        // Add possible template part to array
        $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

        // Get the correct template part
        $template_part = str_replace( get_template_directory() . '/', '', locate_template( $templates ) );
        $template_part = str_replace( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/', '', $template_part );

        // Add template part if found
        if ( $template_part != '' ) {
            // log $template_part
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The locate_template function is only used in a conditional to find a file I specify, correct? And then if I have it hook into get_header, I have to write a function to display "header.php" on the front-end if locate_template for header.php returns true? Just trying to confirm I'm thinking about this right. Thanks. :-)

Comment: yes, you're using locate_template strictly to see if templates exist. you don't have to do anything on the get_ hooks except test and log, those functions just trigger the actions and continue doing their thing on their own.

Answer (score 0):

**Play along with:**

```
echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', str_replace(str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-content/', '', array_slice(str_replace('\\', '/', get_included_files()), (array_search(str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-includes/template-loader.php', str_replace('\\', '/', get_included_files())) + 1)))).'</li></ul>';
```

HTML-list with all template files in use for the current landing page, including all template-parts from plugins, child theme and/ or parent theme combinations, all in one line of code.

Written at:

[How do you find out which template page is serving the current page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page/)

if `admin-bar stuff` path is showing at the top, or any other file, change the filename `template-loader.php` in this line of code to: whatever filname you need to break from.

if you need this in the admin bar, **use the right priotity** (earliest) **to make shure no files are entered at the end** of this list. For example:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_adminbar_template_monitor', -5);
```

priority `-5` make shure it loads first. The key is to render this line at the right moment.

Do some changes if your server using dubble-slashes.