# Show template loaded

Tags: templates, list

Is there any way to see what .php files are being loaded for a particular page?

So say I have a page - www.example.com/page - and on it is loading the header.php, sidebar.php, footer.php, and the page.php, and any other php from plugins. Is there anyway to get a list of these for a certain page?

Comment: Are you referring only to files that are used for templating? Or all PHP files, even those that have no html inside them?

Comment: Might wanna try an older question of mine: (Is there a hook or function I can use to display all theme files being used on a current page?): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168146/is-there-a-hook-or-function-i-can-use-to-display-all-theme-files-being-used-on-a

Comment: @RachieVee this is probably a stupid question, but can I put all the code from the first example in functions.php? Obviously with the required php tags.

Comment: @CalvT Sure can. It's neater G.M.'s way but I also dropped it all in functions.php because I needed to see what it can do first. Just make sure that printing function goes in your footer file. Good luck!

Comment: @RachieVee It works great - but only shows the included theme files? Not the plugin ones? Did you find this?

Comment: @CalvT Unfortunately it only shows the files from the theme - the guys there meant to provide a starting point for me, so it's a good base to work off of. I'm not sure how to detect plugin only files - that sounds like it can be a new question if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @RachieVee http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172461/show-list-of-loaded-php-files-from-plugins

Answer (score 3):

The following will show the current template file to logged in admins only.  If you add to the top of your functions file, you should see this info as the first line.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');

function show_template() {
  global $template;
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ($current_user->user_level == 10 ) print_r($template);
}
```

You will still need to follow the logic of the page template to determine which header, sidebar and footer are loaded, however.

Comment: this might only `show page.php` or `header.php`, but not `footer.php`, `sidebar.php`, or other templates that may be loaded

Comment: Not if you call `get_template_part`

Answer (score 2):

get_currentuserinfo is deprecated since 4.5.0! Use wp_get_current_user() instead.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');

function show_template() {
  global $template;
  global $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user();
  if ($current_user->user_level == 10 ) print_r($template);
}
```